# What to use for Python string.find?

Tags: python, string, find, deprecated

The [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html) for Python 2.7 lists `string.find` as a deprecated function but does not (unlike `atoi` and `atol`) provide an alternative.

I'm coding in 2.7 at the moment so I'm happy to use it but I would like to know:

- what is it going to be replaced with?
- is that usable in 2.7 (if so, I'll use it now so as to avoid recoding later)?

Comment: What part of the documentation are you reading?  Why are you using the `string` module?

Comment: Turns out the documentation I was reading was the _wrong_ documentation. Serves me right for blindly following Google links without thinking. Thanks, all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Almost the entire `string` module has been moved to the `str` type as method functions.

Why are you using the `string` module, when almost everything you need is already part of the string type?

http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.find

The string type -- and it's methods -- is not deprecated.  Indeed, it will me morphed to include Unicode in Python 3.

Comment: Because I program in Python about twice a year :-) But apologies to all, I _am_ using the class, I just found the wrong doco. Stupid! Stupid! Stupid!

Answer (score 6):

A lot of methods in string have been replaced by the str class.  Here is [str.find](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.find).